# Did Firefox 48 remove ability to style the select element?

Tags: html, css, firefox

It seems like with the latest version of Firefox (48) they have removed the ability to style select option elements with CSS?

Previously I had a select element styled as such

[image: firefox 47 style of select element]

Now in Forefox 48 it looks like this.

[image: firefox 48 removes CSS style of select element]

Is there a way to style this using CSS in Firefox 48? Is there are statement from Firefox on this, I could not find any information?

Comment: What version of FF were you using before? I looked through the [release notes for version48](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/48.0/releasenotes/) but didnt see anything related to select. Are you using [-moz-appearance : none;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance) that may help you.

Comment: I was using version 47, I tried the -moz-appearance: none; and on the select element it removed the arrow, on the option element it did nothing.

Comment: I only suggested the -moz-appearance because it removes the standard class elements that a browser puts on input elements. Perhaps people could help you if you added your CSS

Comment: what was your original HTML/CSS?

Comment: I have now noticed on different computers running both firefox 48 and 49 this issue can not be replicated. I am assuming at this point it was a local issue, of which I am at this point unaware what is causing it.

Comment: well the PC that this issue is running on is now running firefox 49 and the issue still persists, wondering if there is some plugin or program on my pc causing this? should I try and re-install firefox?

Answer (score 2):

This seemed to do the trick for me. `-moz-appearance: none;` opens up the element for slight modifications:

CSS

```
option {
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
option.active {
  background: black;
  color: orange;
}
```

HTML

```
<select>
  <option>- Select a Page -</option>
  <option class="active">Home Page</option>
  <option>About Us</option>
  <option>Camping Tips</option>
</select>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8L9eduvy/2/)

**Could not find a statement from Mozilla about this.*

Comment: Best way to get a statement from them is to complain on Bugzilla and let them wontfix it and school you on why they made that decision.