# JS/CSS Code working for Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some html and JavaScript for a select drop-down box. When the user selects the color I want the background of the selected option to successfully update with the color of the background.

In the code I am experiencing what is occurring with Firefox, when you hover over a select option it changes the hover color to blue, and when you select it it takes that background color.

When I run the exact same code in Chrome, it successfully uses the background color of the selected option.

What can I do to make this cross platform compatible and work?

```js
    $("#color_me1").change(function(){
        var color = $("option:selected", this).css("background-color");
        $("#color_me1").css("background-color", color);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Color One:</label>
    <select id="color_me1" name="color1">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select color -- </option>
        <option value="800000" style="background-color:#800000">Maroon</option>
        <option value="FF0000" style="background-color:#FF0000">Red</option>
        <option value="FFA500" style="background-color:#FFA500">Orange</option>
        <option value="FFFF00" style="background-color:#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
        <option value="808000" style="background-color:#808000">Olive</option>
        <option value="008000" style="background-color:#008000">Green</option>
        <option value="800080" style="background-color:#800080">Purple</option>
        <option value="FF00FF" style="background-color:#FF00FF">Fuchsia</option>
        <option value="00FF00" style="background-color:#00FF00">Lime</option>
        <option value="008080" style="background-color:#008080">Teal</option>
        <option value="00FFFF" style="background-color:#00FFFF">Aqua</option>
        <option value="0000FF" style="background-color:#0000FF">Blue</option>
        <option value="000080" style="background-color:#000080">Navy</option>
        <option value="808080" style="background-color:#808080">Gray</option>
        <option value="FFFFFF" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">White</option>
    </select>
    <br>
```

[image]

Comment: Styling of form elements is not consistent across clients. All you could do is work with proprietary CSS for a particular client.

Comment: it could be a bug in Firefox, or maybe they just don't support that feature. It's not controlled by any standard which would apply to all browsers. Quick internet research shows it may be a bug, although Firefox claim to have fixed it, others beg to differ. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147362/firefox-overriding-style-of-html-select-option, for instance

Comment: related: https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1141257

Comment: `$("#color_me1")` throws null, which is the reason your color is not changing. As others mentioned, it could be the issue with browser or the library not supporting that browser method.

Comment: The color is changing to the hover background color. Default when you select an option it has the text in black and the background white, when using this it just takes the background color of when you hover an option, basically the blue.

Is there any workaround or way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why that happens, but this works:

```
$("#color_me1").change(function(){
    var color = $("option:selected", this).get(0).style.backgroundColor
    $("#color_me1").css("background-color", color);
});
```

Or using JavaScript:

```
$("#color_me1").change(function(){
     var selectedOption = this.selectedOptions[0]
     var color = selectedOption.style.backgroundColor
    $("#color_me1").css("background-color", color);
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NELLNx

Comment: Thank you very much, this issue kind of threw me off, I appreciate the two different solutions.

Comment: @97WaterPolo Glad to help!